# how can I find out which websites are linking to mine?

Tags: backlinks, rss, tools, hyperlink

How can I have a RSS of new sites that link to mine?

I would like to know which sites are linking to us.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When somebody clicks from another site to your site via a link, the browser usually sends you a referrer header that tells you that they came from an external source.  You can see these in your log files.  Most analytics software will give you are report on these as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use google for that, simply write `link:yoursite.com` and google will give you the pages/sites linking to your site in the results.

Comment: yes in blogs search i can get RSS for it and put in and subscribe in google reader or outlook

Comment: If I understand correctly (which I hope), you want to create an RSS feed of the sites linking to your page, and view it in google reader or any other RSS readers? Neither of the tools sundeep and I referred to you has this capability, though this can be achieved trough custom development. You need to create an application that crawls google results and creates the RSS feed on a regular basis. Altough the google webmaster tools allows the link data to be exported into a csv, but you'll have to create the feed manualy.

Comment: Today, at least, **link:yoursite.com** does no such thing.

Comment: `link:` does not work any more and I can't find reference as of when was it discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

Search Engines like Google are providing tools, may find [this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2007/02/discover-your-links.html) useful.